AI Stops Abruptly with Langchain and CTransformers
I am facing an issue with my AI application in Python. I am using the chainlit library along with langchain and CTransformers to generate AI responses. However, the AI often stops abruptly before completing the response.
The main issue seems to be that the AI stops generating responses prematurely (example), even though I have increased max_context_length and max_new_tokens.
import chainlit as cl
from langchain.callbacks.base import BaseCallbackHandler
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain_community.llms import CTransformers
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate


class StreamHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = cl.Message(content="")

    async def on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs):
        await self.msg.stream_token(token)

    async def on_llm_end(self, response: str, **kwargs):
        await self.msg.send()
        self.msg = cl.Message(content="")


llm = CTransformers(
    model="/Users/memo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/llama_files",
    model_file="llama-2-7b-chat.Q6_K.gguf",
    model_type="llama",
    max_context_length=4096,
    max_new_tokens=512
)

template = """
[INST] <<SYS>>
You are an AI assistant specialized in analyzing and interpreting regulations and legal texts.
You provide comprehensive, accurate and factual responses based on the given instructions.
Your answers should be detailed, professional, and relevant to the field of regulatory analysis.
Always provide a concise answer and use the following Context:
{context}
<</SYS>>
User:
{instruction}[/INST]"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["context", "instruction"])


@cl.on_chat_start
def on_chat_start():
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="context")
    llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm, verbose=False, memory=memory)
    cl.user_session.set("llm_chain", llm_chain)


@cl.on_message
async def on_message(message: cl.Message):
    llm_chain = cl.user_session.get("llm_chain")

    await llm_chain.ainvoke(
        message.content,
        config={"callbacks": [cl.AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler(), StreamHandler()]},
    )

Can anyone help me figure out what might be going wrong?
